# React Selector: passing onChange event back through two components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I'm trying to pass an onChange event from React selector through two components back up to the parent App. Using what is below, the e.target.value is undefined, so it seems the event is not coming back. What is incorrect?

Parent App, by passing selectCity all the way down, I was assuming the event e should come back to it.

```
  selectCity = e => {
     console.log('filter city' + e.target.value)
     this.setState({
        filteredBuildings: this.state.filteredBuildings.filter((b) =>
        b.filterOptions.city === e.target.value)
     })
   }

   <FilterSection
      cityFilterOptions={this.getCityFilterOptions()}
      selectCity={this.selectCity}
   />
```

Middle Component, FilterSection, simply passing the *selectCity* :

```
const FilterSection = props =>
    <div className="filter-section">
       <Filter
           cityFilterOptions={props.cityFilterOptions}
           selectCity={props.selectCity}
       />    
     </div>
```

Child Component, trying to set the *selectCity* function to the onChange event.

```
        return (
        <div className="filter-row">
            <div className="filter">
                <Select
                    onChange={this.props.selectCity}
                    className="basic-single"
                    classNamePrefix="select"
                    isClearable={true}
                    isSearchable={true}
                    name="color"
                    options={this.props.cityFilterOptions}
                    placeholder="All Cities"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Please show **reproducible** example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), making a sandbox like codesandbox.io is pretty common

Comment: It looks to me like you're passing the onChange correctly. Could the problem be in the <option> tag itself? Maybe its value is actually undefined?

Comment: <option> tag is fine because the list is populating, and I can see the value in the component updating when I select one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing event as a parameter to this.props.selectCity like this: `onChange={(e)=>this.props.selectCity(e)}` also check your this.props.cityFilterOptions that might not be returning the correct result.

Comment: That works. To note, I also had to change e.target.value to just e.value for some reason.